# How to disable standard ant tasks?

Tags: java, ant

Some tasks in Ant have some pretty strange behavior. For example, javac silently ignores the executable attribute if fork is not set to true. Another example is the copy task that silently ignores copying files if it means overwriting another file.

We have made our own tasks where it is more difficult to make mistakes. You always need to specify overwrite=true/false for example.

Is there a way to disable the standard javac and copy tasks so that people don't use them accidentally?

I don't want to provide a custom ant release.

There is a file that is imported from all build scripts that imports our own ant tasks so it would be possible to *undefine* an ant task here if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible without creating your own Ant release by removing task implementation classes from the ant jars.